# How to send email in Django to register account?

Tags: python, django, email

I want to create a signup form that sends an activation key to user. This sent email shows a log-in activation link to continue to create a account. Now what i did is that i wrote these lines in my settings.py file to sent email.

```
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS=7
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'emailaddress@gamil.com'
```

but this is not working well or may be the way i am using this is wrong. I need your help to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us your "send-email" function ?

Comment: What does 'not working well' mean? Is it working or not? However, hope you didn't give your username and password as blank in your code too... :)

Comment: @Liarez thank's for reply. i am new to django framework. i followed this article http://www.michelepasin.org/blog/2011/01/14/setting-up-django-registration/ to know about this. Can you please guide me.This links says nothing about email function

Comment: @HasanIqbalAnik i mean it's not working like what i want! and what to put in host or password?

Comment: if you working on your local machine set EMAIL_USE_TLS = True, or comment this line. then test.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507843/how-to-use-gmail-as-your-smtp-server-for-youtrack

Comment: @TameenMalik ANS updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this settings in your setting.py.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_HOST_USER='your gmail user name'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='your gmail password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

Test Email configuration :
in your command line :

```
$ python manage.py shell

from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail("testing", "Did this work?", "no-reply@abc.net", ["email where you want to send ", ], fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: value error: need more than one value to unpack in smtp.py file

Comment: Have to try this line properly :
send_mail("testing", "Did this work?", "abc@gmail.com", ["abc@gmail.com"], fail_silently=False)

Comment: thank you yogesh ! :) one more thing how to send activation key and how to receive that?

Comment: for authentication which app are you using?

Comment: yogesh i am using 'django.contrib.auth'.

Comment: you can use custom user model or any one already build app for login and registration.
http://www.sofokus.com/blogi/custom-user-model/
http://www.roguelynn.com/words/django-custom-user-models/

Comment: can you please provide me some helpful links about these user models.

Comment: http://www.sofokus.com/blogi/custom-user-model/
http://www.roguelynn.com/words/django-custom-user-models/
http://blackglasses.me/2013/09/17/custom-django-user-model/

Answer (score 2):

This hast nothing to to with Django or Python, you're Gmail details are misconfigured

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
```

Above needs to be set to your Gmail user (email) and password

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

TLS is required, it needs to be set to `True`. In consequence port has to be set to SMTP over SSL, which is `465`